# How to convert dataframe <class "str"> to dataframe

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, types

i've got dataframe with column "cc" that contain dataframes. But i can't manipulate it because it is str.

```
   Unnamed: 0   a    b                    cc
0           0  51  101 Unnamed: 0         ...
1           1  51  102 Unnamed: 0         ...
2           2  52  101 Unnamed: 0         ...
3           3  52  102 Unnamed: 0         ...
```

`df.cc.iloc[0]` shows me what it contains, but it is a string:

What is the way to extract dataframe?
where am i wrong?

`a = df.cc.iloc[0] print(a.head())`

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'head'

or

`a = df.cc.iloc[0] b = df.cc.iloc[0] c = pd.concat([a, b], ignore_index=True)`

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type <class 'str'>; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If select first value of column ouput is single value - here string. So cannot use pandas functions for scalar.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cc':['a','b']})
                         
print (df.cc.iloc[0])
a
```

If really need one element Series use double `[]`:

```
a = df.cc.iloc[[0]]
print (a)
0    a
Name: cc, dtype: object
```

Of one element DataFrame:

```
a = df[['cc']].iloc[[0]]
print (a)
  cc
0  a
```

Generate by DataFrame constructor:

```
a = df.cc.iloc[0]
print (a)
a

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col':[a]})
print (df1)
  col
0   a
```

If fill each value of `cc` column full new DataFrame it is not best practices, but if select first value is returned DataFrame:

```
def qwe(y,z): 
    df = pd.DataFrame({"one":range(1,10), "two":range(2,11), "three":range(3,12)}) 
    df["four"] = (df.one * (y+z)) + (df.two * (y+z)) + (df.three * (y+z)) 
    return df 

fr = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b"]) 

for aa in range(1, 5): 
    for bb in range(1, 5): 
        x = [aa,bb] 
        fr.loc[len(fr)] = x
```

---

```
#for each value in cc is set DataFrame
fr["cc"] = fr.apply(lambda x: qwe(x['a'], x['b']), axis=1) 
print(fr.cc)
0        one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
1        one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
2        one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
3        one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
4        one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
5        one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
6        one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
7        one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
8        one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
9        one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
10       one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
11       one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
12       one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
13       one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
14       one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
15       one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3   ...
Name: cc, dtype: object
```

---

```
print(fr.cc.iloc[0])
   one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3    12
1    2    3      4    18
2    3    4      5    24
3    4    5      6    30
4    5    6      7    36
5    6    7      8    42
6    7    8      9    48
7    8    9     10    54
8    9   10     11    60
```

EDIT: If need join each DataFrame from `fr.cc` column use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with list comprehension:

```
out = pd.concat([x for x in fr.cc])
print(out)
    one  two  three  four
0     1    2      3    12
1     2    3      4    18
2     3    4      5    24
3     4    5      6    30
4     5    6      7    36
..  ...  ...    ...   ...
4     5    6      7   144
5     6    7      8   168
6     7    8      9   192
7     8    9     10   216
8     9   10     11   240

[144 rows x 4 columns]
```

If mixed `cc` column - DataFrames with strings:

```
out = pd.concat([x for x in fr.cc if isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame)])
print(out)
    one  two  three  four
0     1    2      3    12
1     2    3      4    18
2     3    4      5    24
3     4    5      6    30
4     5    6      7    36
..  ...  ...    ...   ...
4     5    6      7   144
5     6    7      8   168
6     7    8      9   192
7     8    9     10   216
8     9   10     11   240

[144 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: @Andy - What does not work?

Comment: I need to get dataframe that in df.cc.iloc[0]. But a =  df.cc.iloc[[0]] retrive an object

Comment: @Andy - `a = df.cc.iloc[[0]] ` return `Series`, for DataFrame is added solutions to answer.

Comment: i did simple example:def qwe(y,z):
    'df = pd.DataFrame({"one":range(1,10), "two":range(2,11), "three":range(3,12)})
    df["four"] = (df.one * (y+z)) + (df.two * (y+z)) + (df.three * (y+z))
    return df

fr = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b"])
for aa in range(1, 5):
    for bb in range(1, 5):
        x = [aa,bb]
        fr.loc[len(fr)] = x

fr["cc"] = fr.apply(lambda x: qwe(x['a'], x['b']), axis=1)

print(fr.cc.iloc[0].head(5))' and it is working: '

Comment: @Andy If use `print(fr.cc.iloc[0].head(5))` it is same `'some string'.head(5)`, so error is expected. Question is what need?

Comment: but this code retrive^one  two  three  four
0    1    2      3    12
1    2    3      4    18
2    3    4      5    24
3    4    5      6    30
4    5    6      7    36' but why in another case it is a class str???

Comment: @Andy - because assign to cell in column `cc` DataFrame. It is not best practices do it.

Comment: @Andy - In my opinion main message is if check `cc` column by `print(fr.cc)` and something weird ouput (like here) it is not good solution, pandas can do it, but not recommended.

Comment: the main goal is to concat all of dataframe in column cc and manipulate over it. But in my real example df.cc.iloc[0] is a string. and df[["cc"]].iloc[[0]] do not retrive dataframe

Comment: @Andy - now understand. Need `out = pd.concat([x for x in fr.cc])`, right?

Comment: yes. you are right. But i cant do it in real example till it is a string

Comment: is there vectorized way to do final dataframe avoiding dataframe of datafmames and concatenation?

Comment: i found!!! I save to_csv my df After generating dataframe of dataframes. After reading from csv i got cell with df  in df as string. How to read it correctly? Is there a way to parse df?

Comment: @Andy - `I save to_csv my df` - ooops, it is very bad idea, if need ave ouput need `pickle` instead like `df.to_pickle('file.pkl')` and for read `df = pd.read_pickle('file.pkl')` for avoid convert dataframes to strings.